# If $G$ has minimum degree $k$, prove or disprove that $G$ contains a path/cycle of length at least $k$, that contains $x$

Tags: graph-theory

> If $G$ has minimum degree $k$, prove or disprove that $G$ contains a path/cycle of length at least $k$, that contains $x$.

I really don't know where to start with this question:

[image]

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

I have considered a longest path containing $x$, as I know $x$ has at least $k$ neighbours. I have considered $x$ being the start vertex on such longest path.

I am told that (1) is true and (2) is false, however I do not know how to come up with a proof/counter example.

I don't understand why (2) is false. For example, take the cycle graph. The minimum degree of a cycle is 2, and for any vertex $x$, the cycle contains $x$. So surely (2) is true?

Comment: Your attempt with maximal paths starting at $x$ is fine. Assume that path is $x_0x_1x_2\ldots x_r$ ( incidentally, with $x_0=x$). Can you see how to extend that path with an “unused” vertex if $r<k$?

For the second question: Start with a star graph around $x$ and replace each leaf by something suitable

Comment: Okay, so here is my approach for (i). We can construct a path of length k as follows. Let x be the starting vertex and we know this has atleast k neighbours. Choose one of these atleast k neighbours as the next vertex in the path, and call it x1. x1 has atleast k neighbours, and atleast k-1 neighbours not used in the path thus far. Pick one of the atleast k-1 neighbours and add this to the path, and call it x2. We continue in this way until we reach xk which has (k-k = 0) neighbours not used in the path thus far. This produces a path of length k? For part (ii), I am still unsure :/

Answer (score 1):

To see why (2) is false, two triangles connected by a path of length 2. The vertex in the center of the path is not contained in a cycle

To see why (1) is true, consider the connected component $C_x$ that contanis $x$. The minimum degree of $C_x$ is greater than $\delta(G$). Now consider $P=v_1...v_n$ a path of maximal length that contains $x$ in $C_x$. Since $d(v_1)\geq k$ then $|N(v_1)|\geq k$, and also every vertice $u\in N(v_1)$ should be in $P$ because if not, then $u v_1..v_n$ would be a path larger than $P$ that contains $x$. So $|P|\geq k$.

Comment: For (2) the question states that the minimum degree of g is atleast 2 so g cannot be a tree?

Comment: I didnt see it. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

To see why (2) cannot be true for *any* positive integer $k$, consider the following counterexample: The vertex-set of the graph consists of a vertex $x$ plus $k$ vertex-disjoint cliques $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots, Y_k$ of $k+1$ vertices each [and each $Y_i$ disjoint from $x$ too], and for each $i=1,\ldots,k$, there is an edge in $G$ from $x$ to exactly one vertex $y_i\in Y_i$. Note that $G$ has minimum degree $k+1$, yet $x$ does not participate in ANY cycle, nevermind one of length $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the question states that G has minimum degree k, I am not sure where you got the k+1 from

Comment: @Billy A clique of $k+1$ vertices is such that every vertex is incident to exactly $k$ edges i.e., has degree precisely $k$.